# TFS 2013 cannot find MSTest.exe

Tags: tfs

We've just upgraded to TFS 2013 and all our build templates are failing now, because it cannot find MSTest. It appears to be using the path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools..\IDE\MSTest.exe

Which does not refer to a copy of MSTest.exe. Does anyone know where this is defined, and how I can change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were a couple of problems with the install of TFS 2013.

- We needed to install a better version of TFS on the build server than VS2013 Express, as express doesn't include MSTest.exe
- We needed to update our custom build template to remove references to the TFS 2010 libraries
- Restart the build agent process to detect changes to environmental variables

Lots of this advice was garnered from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd647548.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You must replace with Ms Test with `Test Runner on your settings` it's news on ALM 2013

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aghilas, where can I find that dialog?

Comment: I happy to help you Ceilingfish, right click on yor build definition, select process setting and choice sub section of test

Comment: To clarify: If you are using the "Default Template" build process template, or another one with similar settings (e.g. not the "Upgrade template"), then from your Builds list, Edit Build Definition, go to the "Process" section of the definition, and put your input focus into the Automated Tests field, then click the [...] button that appears to edit it. In the editing dialog that appears, click "Edit..." and this dialog will be shown.

Comment: This worked after I installed the Visual Studio Test Agent 2013 with my TFS Express 2013 install.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone...

I've just encountered a similar problem on our build server, and was able to rectify it by installing Visual Studio 2013 on it - for some reason it didn't spot the VS 2012 tools that were already present and which had been working with TFS 2012.